# High-side switch with BJT for 24V controlled by logic level

Tags: microcontroller, bjt, switching, high-side

Earlier I have asked another [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/396150/high-side-switch-for-24v-controlled-by-logic-level/) and I got very good answers but I couldn't get a solid success as per my size considerations and an unexpected solenoid type change. And I am now giving another try this time using small signal transistors instead of FET's.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f50rV7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this design I can have a good ON and OFF using 5V, 12V supplies but not with 24V. If the input is `HIGH` I can get a full ON (24V) but, if I put the input in `LOW` state, I have sort of half ON (12.4V). I have tried different resistor values considering saturation and cut-off currents but I couldn't make any difference by that.

I appreciate your valuable inputs from now and I am open to any other suggestions in terms of design.

Note that: I have just picked the transistors randomly from common examples. 2N3906 is rated for a maximum 200mA, not sure it is even good enough for my load.

Comment: Hi, Sener. When you add schematics using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar you can save the editable version inline with your post. No need for an account and no need for screengrabs with the grid in them and having to uplaod the image. That way you can edit later and we can copy an editable schematic into our answers.

Comment: I knew so. But, I can't save it because I don't have account. If I can't save, it doesn't give me a link to share. I was wondering how you guy are doing this?

Comment: Simply edit your post, press the schematics button, draw your circuit, press save. Voilá!

Comment: @Sener: Read my comment again - carefully!

Comment: Ah, you are right @Transistor, there is an embedded feature in SE.

Comment: What load resistor did you have?

Comment: I don't have the solenoid (and a proper datasheet) at hand yet. I expect tomorrow or so. So, I don't know the exact resistance of the Solenoid, only 24V and 1.5W power consumption. It is a small air valve solenoid.
If you have something in your mind for testing purposes I like to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFUHbD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Switch driven by 5 V squarewave. Solenoid represented by 1 µH inductor (in the absence of any other information) with 390 Ω (1.5 W) resistance. *

[image]

*Figure 2. The CircuitLab simulation results.*

It looks OK to me. If you have problems then measure the voltages at various points and add them into your schematic using the NODE circuit element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts to test the design. I will check again and come back with my findings.

Comment: I found the issue. It was a silly one. Collector and Emitter of Q3 were reversed in the prototyping pcb. Once it is corrected, it shows a solid ON and OFF as you stated in the simulator. So, now I need to realize if the solenoid will work as estimated with this design. Thanks again.